# MVC type framework for WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any sort of framework like ASP.NET MVC available for WPF?  I know the principles can be applied to both desktop and web applications, e.g. with commands instead of requests being routed to actions in WPF etc.

PS I also miss model based, wizard generated code in WPF.  The MVC stuff is hardly prize winning, but it makes life a lot easier than coding absolutely every view by hand, from scratch, like I now have to do in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard design pattern for WPF code is MVVM (Model View, ViewModel), and there are a couple of frameworks for that available, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using

Comment: Thanks.  MVVM is pretty much my standard for MVC as well.